# NavigationController Pushing TabBarViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have noticed that my GoogleMap stopped working in the sense that it has become inactive after first touch. This got me thinking, so I decided to create a new project with the same code to check to see if it was the code and shows that its not my GoogleMaps code. I think it has to do with how I set up my Navigation Bar and Tab Bar.

This is what I have. I have an initial ViewController inside a NavigationController. This view controller does many things, one of which is push view controllers. I have a button that pushes a UITabBarController onto the NavigationController stack. I have created a UITabBarController inside storyboard and gave that controller a StoryboardID: GRxTabBarViewController. GRxTabBarViewController has 4 view controllers, PricesViewController, SavingsViewController, InfoViewController, and MapsViewController.

I then created the header and implementation files of these controllers. This is what I have in my initial view controller to push this tab bar controller and tab bars.

```
-(void)pushTabBar
{
        UIStoryboard *iPhoneStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        GRxTabBarViewController *tabViewController = (GRxTabBarViewController*) [iPhoneStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GRxTabBarViewController"];

        PricesViewController *pricesController = [tabViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

        SavingsViewController *savingsController = [tabViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

        InfoViewController *infoController = [tabViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];

        MapsViewController *mapController = [tabViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];

        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:infoController];
        UINavigationController *savingsNav  = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:savingsController];

        UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[tabViewController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0];
        [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-prices-selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-prices-normal"]];
        UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [[tabViewController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:1];
        [tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-savings-selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-savings-normal"]];
        UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [[tabViewController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:2];
        [tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-info-selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-info-normal"]];
        UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [[tabViewController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:3];
        [tabBarItem4 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-map-selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-map-normal"]];

        [tabViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pricesController, savingsNav, navController, mapController, nil]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabViewController animated:YES];
}
```

GRxTabBarViewController is a UITabBarController and has this in the implementation file.

GRxTabBarViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissTab) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20.0f, 44.0f);
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}

-(void)dismissTab
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Am I setting up my tab bar incorrectly? Has someone pushed a tab bar before and have any ideas what I am doing wrong that can help me out? Any guidance or help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you made this tab bar controller in a storyboard, why are you instantiating a couple of navigation controllers and setting the tab bar controller's viewControllers in code? You should do all that in the storyboard. It's also probably not a good idea to push a tab bar controller, it's almost always the root view controller of the window. What are you doing in the controller that pushes the tab bar controller?

Comment: @rdelmar I actually didn't want to use storyboard at all but all of the tutorials I found used it in storyboard. And it wouldn't change if I do it in storyboard or in the viewcontroller. It would just be less code. And the reason is that the initial view controller has many options and not only pushes this tab bar controller.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for pushViewController:animated:, this is what it says about the view controller parameter: "The view controller that is pushed onto the stack. This object cannot be an instance of tab bar controller and it must not already be on the navigation stack." I think you need to rethink your app structure.

Comment: @rdelmar what if I push a navigationController that has a tab bar controller? Or what if it's a modal? I actually made an application like this before, and got released onto the App Store. Everything in my current App works, just not GoogleMaps after first touch.

Comment: The first thing I would do is test to see if it's the push that's causing the problem. In pushTabBar, replace the push with self.view.window.rootViewController =  tabViewController;. That will just replace your initial controller with the tab bar controller as the root view controller of the window. See if that fixes the problem.